# My proof that the empty set is unique

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that the empty set is unique.

**Proof:**

Let $U = \{ a \}$ be the universal set.

Assume $a \not\in \emptyset '$ and $a \not\in \emptyset$.

Without loss of generality, since $a \not\in \emptyset'$, $\emptyset '$ does not contain any elements. Since $\emptyset '$ does not contain any elements, it must by default be a subset of $\emptyset$, since the conditional statement

$$a \in \emptyset ' \Rightarrow \emptyset ' \subseteq \emptyset$$

is vacuously true.

Therefore, since $\emptyset' \subseteq \emptyset$ and $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset '$, we have that $\emptyset ' = \emptyset$. $\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

I would appreciate it if people could please provide feedback as to the correctness of my proof.

EDIT: Please be specific about what is incorrect and why. That way, I can learn what I did wrong and improve much more effectively.

Comment: You should not need a universal set. Also, please be more careful with writing down the definition of what being empty means

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Are you saying that my proof is wrong, or that there are better ways to prove the theorem? Please be more specific about which part is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty set is a subset of any set. Let $A$ and $B$ be two empty sets. Since $A$ is empty, then $A \subseteq B$. Similarly, $B \subseteq A$. Hence $A=B$.

EDIT: Your assumptions are a bit suspicious and the use of the universal set is really unnecessary. Basically the part: assume $a\notin \emptyset'$ and $\emptyset'$ does not contain any elements is a bit wordy and I am not sure if it is a valid logic flow. The rest of your solution is pretty much the idea that I uncover above. All you need to claim is that two sets are empty and then use the fact that they are subsets of each-other.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two empty sets.
Then the assertions $x\in A$ and $x\in B$ are logically equivalent.
By the definition of equality of sets, $A=B$ iff $\forall x(x\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\in B)$, it follows that $A=B$.

Comment: This is not definition, this is an axiom. The definition will be closer to $\forall x(x\in A\Longleftrightarrow x\in B)\land \forall w(A\in w\iff B\in w)$

Comment: @SvanN because axiom and definition are different things, there are models(not of ZF) where extensionality is not an axiom